# Still not understanding SVN Repositories in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am about to import my project into svn but don't want to stuff it up.

My structure is like this:

Repositories:

> /var/svn/client_name1/
>
> /var/svn/client_name2/

Project directories under /var/svn/client_name1/

> ```
>                  project1/
>                           trunk/
>                           branches/ 
>                           tags/
>                  project2/
>                           trunk/
>                           branches/ 
>                           tags/
> ```

My Apache config looks like this:

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/svn
SVNListParentPath on
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Repository"
AuthUserFile /etc/svnpass
Require valid-user
AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svnauth
</Location>
```

Now I can access my svn repository

> http://mysite.com/svn/client_name1/

however, there are no projects displayed here, just a Revision 0 message (is that correct)?

I can connect to the repository in eclipse using the same url.

If I want to place an existing project into the repository what url do I use?

> http://mysite.com/svn/client_name1/project1

OR

> http://mysite.com/svn/client_name1/project1/trunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my set up as:
    http://mysite.com/svn/client_name1/project1/trunk

So that I have:

```
/project
    /trunk
    /branches
    /tags
```

With appropriate "copies" of the project in /branches and /tags.  While copies use "svn copy", they only need to copy changes from the baseline.

Comment: ok, so when elcipse asks me where to export to, I select http://mysite.com/svn/client_name1 and then type project1/trunk as the export path.  Does this sound correct?

Comment: Exactly.  I just tried it.  Share Project, Select SVN, select which project, then enter your folder name as "/project/trunk", click next, edit the "initial import" message as you see fit and click Finish.

Comment: Now I am confused.  It worked but on my server when I go to /var/svn/clientname/ the project is not there.  Should there be the project name here?  Where has it gone?  When I view it on the web it works, I can browse the files.

Comment: It doesn't exist as a series of files/folders. It is stored in the SVN database which you could find at /var/svn/db.  Don't touch that.  If you want to work on it on the system, check it out there using the command line tools. "svn help" on the command line for more info about that.